# How to run a loop every 15 sec and to update the result on the same figure?

Tags: python, loops, plot

I'm creating a simple code to analyze data from a particular folder. The thing is, every 15 seconds new data files are created in the folder, and I need to analyze these new ones and plot them.

I'm trying to have a figure, which is automatically updated every time after the analyses.

The problematic place is the main loop. I don't know how to correctly loop the process of analyses and plotting every 15 seconds.

The figure is not updated after each cycle run.

```py
#MAIN LOOP


T_step = 15 
while True:
    try:
        T_start = time.time() #current time for filtering new files

        my_data= Save_data(path) #save the data from files 

        [tot_voltage, aver_voltage]=Average_signal(my_data) #analyse the data

        std_dev=np.std(tot_voltage, axis=1)  

        x=TimeVector(my_data, tot_voltage)

        PlotAverage(aver_voltage, std_dev, title,x) #plot the analysed data

        time.sleep(T_step) #wait 15 sec, repeat the cycle and update the plot

    except ValueError:
            print("\n Some value error has occurred - probably no new files in the folder")
            break
```

In the code I have some predefined functions, I will put here some of them if it helps:

In the first function  I compare the modification time of the files with (`T_start`-15 seconds). If it is higher, then the file is new and I analyze it.

```py
def Save_data(path):
    my_data = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(path): 
        if os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path,filename)) > (T_start - T_step):
            try:
                data = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(path,filename), skip_header = skip_head) 
                my_data[filename] = data[:, [0,1]]
            except IndexError:
    return my_data


def PlotAverage(aver_voltage, std_dev, title,x):
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.errorbar(x, aver_voltage, yerr=std_dev, fmt='r', ecolor='gray', label = title)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel('Time [mus]')
    plt.ylabel('Voltage [V]')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `break`, otherwise you exit the `while` loop whenever there is no new data.

Also consider add a short `sleep` outside of the `try` block (but still inside the loop) so you aren't polling for the file thousands of times every second.

```
while True:
    try:
        # stuff
    except ValueError:
        print("\n Some value error has occurred - probably no new files in the folder")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Actually, I want to exit the loop when there is no new data:)
And the problem is (even when I changed the sleep according to your comment), while the loop is in progress, the figure window is not responding. Once I do CNTRL+C, the figure appears...

Comment: I tried to make a minimal example that exhibits this behaviour, but if I just wrap something like your PlotAverage function in a loop then that works for me. My suggestion is to find the simplest thing that breaks for you, and then we can debug that.

Comment: Also, it looks like `T_start` is not defined within `Save_data` in the code you posted. I don't know if that's because you didn't post the full code, or it is a genuine error. Might be worth checking the data you are plotting is the data you are expecting to be plotting (and not just the same file again and again, say).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Python code that can update the plotting canvas with data every 15 sec. It used the DataMelt program (https://jwork.org/dmelt). Simply put these lines to the editor, save it a file "test.py", and run it.

```
from java.util import Random
from jhplot  import *
import time

c1 = SPlot()
c1.visible()
c1.setAutoRange()

c1.setMarksStyle('various')
c1.setConnected(1, 0)
c1.setNameX('Time')
c1.setNameY('Data') 

r = Random()
for i in range(100):
   x=r.nextGaussian() 
   y=r.nextGaussian()  
   c1.addPoint(0,x,y,1)
   c1.update()
   time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with the following solution, using `plt.ion()`:

```py
plt.ion()     
while(True):
    try:
        #some analyses, with an example output y:
        y = np.random.random([10,1])
        plt.plot(y)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(15)
        plt.clf()

    except ValueError:
        print("\n Some value error has occurred - probably no new files in the folder")
        break
```